# Linear Algebra Subspace Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

My problem is Let $A$ and $B$ be fixed $2\times 2$ matrices. Prove that the set $W=\{X: XAB=BAX\}$ is a subspace of $M_{2,2}$.

The hints I have are

1. Start with two arbitrary elements of $W$, $X$, and $Y$. Write down the conditions they satisfy.
2. Show that the sum of $X$ and $Y$ still satisfy that condition.
3. Show that any scalar multiple of $X$ still satisfied that condition.

I am really confused on the first hint, and don't really know where to start on this problem. Any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: What's the definition of a subspace of a vector space? Write it down clearly, and then write it down for the specific case when the vector space is $M_{2,2}$.

Comment: My personal approach to this problem would be to show that the map $T\colon M_{2,2}\to M_{2,2}$ given by $T(X)=XAB-BAX$ is linear, and then note that $W=\ker T$. However, if you haven't been introduced to linear maps or kernels yet, then the standard approach of showing that $W$ satisfies the conditions to be a subspace will be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Take X, Y two elements of W. Then they satisfy:
XAB=BAX, YAB=BAY. 
So, for the sum we have (X+Y)AB=XAB+YAB=BAX+BAY=BA(X+Y). 
That means that the sum X+Y belongs to W.
Now for the scalar multiply, (λΧ)(ΑΒ)=λ(ΧΑΒ)=λ(ΒΑΧ)=ΒΑ(λΧ).
That means that λΧ belongs to W.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're trying to solve is cut from the same cloth as many others, which all go something like this: "Here is a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$. Show that $W$ is in fact a subspace." To do this -- that is, to show that $W$ is a subspace -- there are only two things you have to check.

1. Whenever one vector is in $W$, every scalar multiple of that vector is in $W$.
2. Whenever two vectors are in $W$, their sum is in $W$.

As an example, consider the following three subsets of $M_{2,2}$:

- $W_1=\big\{X\in M_{2,2}:\text{at least one of the entries of $X$ is zero}\big\}$.
- $W_2=\big\{X\in M_{2,2}:\text{all of the entries of $X$ are positive}\big\}$.
- $W_2=\big\{X\in M_{2,2}:\text{the diagonal entries entries of $X$ are zero}\big\}$.

$W_1$ satisfies property 1 but not property 2 (why?). $W_2$ satisfies property 2 but not property 1 (why?). And $W_3$ satisfies both properties 1 and 2, meaning that only $W_3$ is a subspace.